# Fancybox video highlight with nothing in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, video, fancybox

I need to play videos in fancybox.

As per  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317242/start-local-video-in-fancybox-mit-jwplayer-video-id-in-url) solution

I started working

My a href tag looks like

```
 <a class="fancybox" href="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/55/myvideo.mp4">
<img class="check" height="120" weight="160" src="/uploads/ckeditor/attachments/55/myvideo.jpg" alt="Myvideo">
</a>
```

and my jquery

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
          fitToView: false, 
          content: '<span></span>', 
          scrolling: 'no', 
   afterLoad: function (){
        this.content = "<embed src='/jwplayer.swf?file=" + this.href + "&autostart=true&amp;wmode=opaque' type='application/mp4' width='140' height='180'></embed>"; 
      }
        });
        });
```

While ckick on that image it fancybox responds with nothing. No error in console and browser

my fancybox content doesn't have apart from the following line

```
<div id="fancybox-content" style="border-width: 10px; width: 0px; height: auto;">
```

please help me.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked for me finally.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    type: "iframe",
    width : 380, // or whatever
    height: 280
}).trigger("click");
});​
```